# Removing a partition with boot flag

Tags: boot, partitioning, boot-partition, flag, parted

I have:

- sda1 (win)
- sda2 (lin)

[image: parted print]

I want to remove the sda1 partition... should I set a boot flag to the sda2 before proceeding?

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea, but probably not necessary (as I'm postulating that the boot loader is in the MBR at the beginning of the disk, rather then in a partition).